# SFTP with public key failing without error

Tags: php, sftp, ssh2-sftp

I'm using `SSH-DSS` key, port is `2222`. I'm able to connect through winscp from my machine using public/private keys (peagent) and username. (Private key is without passphrase)

But when I try the same with PHP script it doesn't work. No error message. `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file()` returns `blank`/`false`. So script ends up with

> **Public Key Authentication Failed**

Is there any method to debug the error?

Public/Private keys are generated with puttygen.

Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
    $methods = array('hostkey' => 'ssh-dss');

    $connection = ssh2_connect('sftp.hostname.com', 2222, $methods);
    if (!$connection) die('Connection failed');

    $publicKeyPath = "./pubKey-OpenSSH";
    $privateKeyPath = "./priKey.ppk";
    echo file_get_contents($publicKeyPath);
    echo "<hr />";
    echo file_get_contents($privateKeyPath);
    echo "<hr />";

    if(ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, 'USERNAME', $publicKeyPath, $privateKeyPath, ""))
    {
        echo "<br /><br /><b>Public Key Authentication Successful</b>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print_r($connection);
        die('<br /><br />Public Key Authentication Failed');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access to the server, you can stop the ssh daemon and start with

```
ssdh -ddd
```

For debugging, and watch for errors there.

Answer (score 0):

Private Key is a ppk. Needs to be a pem or der to work with `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file`. You can use puttygen to convert key to appropriate format by going to Conversions -> Export OpenSSH key